# Rated ampacity of water heater thermostat

Tags: electrical, thermostat, water-heater, aquastat

What is the rated ampacity of "standard" water heater thermostats? The kind you see all over the place from a million different vendors. I cannot seem to find an electrical data sheet on any of them.

Comment: The standard amperage for an electric water heater is 18.8 Amps with 240Volts, 4500 Watt.

Comment: @SteveWellens But there's elements of all sorts of sizes. Are you saying that for more than a 4500W element, the ordinary thermostats don't have sufficient ampacity?

Comment: I'm not saying that.  I just supplied general info.